# Java Swing app trying to populate JComboBox on button click

Tags: java, swing

I am learning Java Swing. I am trying to develop as simple app for learning purpose. There is are multiple issues in following code. I try to read a csv file and populate JComboBox on button click.

```
    public class MyForm {
    private JButton btnRead;
    private JButton btnRead2;
    private JComboBox cbCodes;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private DefaultComboBoxModel comboBoxModel;

    public MyForm(){
        // issue 1: I always get null pointer exception in this line  
        comboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        cbCodes = new JComboBox(comboBoxModel);

        btnRead.addActionListener( e -> {
             List<String[]> data =   readData();
             comboBoxModel.removeAllElements();
             data.forEach(item -> comboBoxModel.addElement(item));
        });

      // issue 2: Since DefaultComboBoxModel was not working. I tried without it. As this I get correct data in the array. But when I make JComboBox with array. Nothing is filled. It is empty. 
      btnRead2.addActionListener( e -> {
            List<String[]> data =   readData();
            String[] array = new String[data.size()];
            data.toArray(array); 
            cbCodes = new JComboBox(array);
        });
    }

   // issue 3: I can't complie the code without this empty method. Why do I need it? 
   // error: Form contains components with Custom Create option but no createUIComponents() method
    void createUIComponents(){
       
    }

    public List<String[]> readData() {
        String file = "data.csv";
        List<String[]> content = new ArrayList<>();
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.contains("\"")){
                    content.add(line.split(" "));
                }
                content.add(line.split(","));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //Some error logging
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyForm");
        frame.setContentPane(new MyForm().mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I make my question in the source code with the comment to show exactly here those issues are involved.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will take you through the steps of creating a Swing GUI.  It's not wise to use a GUI builder.  Building the GUI by hand gives you greater control and teaches you Swing, rather than the GUI builder.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't get the NullPointerException in the lines you indicated, but in the line `btnRead.addActionListener( e -> {` because btnRead has not been initialized yet!
2. When you create a new JComboBox, you have to add it to the panel, too. Just creating it with *new* will not display it. But the real problem behind it is: you're using the model wrong. Write

   ```
       comboBoxModel.removeAllElements();
       for (final String string : array) {
           comboBoxModel.addElement(string);
       }
   ```

to solve that.

3. The problem you have here does not lie within the code you provided, but from another component. At some point, someone used a UI designer. Those designers usually create initialization methods, just like *createUIComponents*. See where that method gets called.

*Synopsis:*

- All in all, your code is really chaotic. Restructure from new, this will clean up a lot of problems.
- - And initialize UI components as soon as possible, best do it in the declaration line:     `private final JButton btnRead = new JButton("Read!");`
- I strongly recommend using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ that will help you write clean code and see and correct problems easier.

Comment: I used IntellJ for this code. I used the GUI tool. As I am learning Swing. I saw few tutorial and   YouTube video. I got an assumeption when I am adding components by the GUI editor tool to the main JPanel it all initialized and adds to panel. I don't need to add it by code as this.mainPanel.add(cbCodes). I added this line to the constructor. Still after the button click and csv file read, it doesn't populates. It is jut empty.

Comment: Yes. In my answer to (2), I showed you some code. Insert this code into your `readData()` method, so the DataModel gets the data. In your method, instead of creating a list and then adding, you can also `comboBoxModel.removeAllElements();` at the start of the method, and when you read each line, simply do a  `comboBoxModel.addElement(line);`